# bash function : splitting name and extension of a file

Tags: bash, function

I have the following function `split` in my .bash_profile file.

```
function split {
   name="${$1%.*}"
   ext="${$1##*.}"
   echo filename=$name extension=$ext
}
```

Now I should expect that the command `split foo.bar` will give me

```
filename=foo  extension=bar
```

But I get get `-bash: ${$1%.*}: bad substitution` error message. The same however works for usual shell variable in a shell script, say `$x` instead of `$1` in .bash_profile (I think the same goes in .bashrc as well).

What's wrong and any remedy?

Comment: And you *do* need quotes where you are passing variables to the `echo` command.

Comment: @Wildcard Maybe grammatically I need to quote after echo. But without quote works in many shells. Also I may skip quotes for variables `name` and `ext` as already pointed out by @SatoKatsura.

Comment: No, it doesn't "work," it does something else entirely.  Your variables will be word split and subjected to glob expansion.  Only by accident will you get the results you expect.  See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/135943).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `$` preceding the variable name (`1`) inside the parameter expansion:

```
name="${1%.*}"
ext="${1##*.}"
```

you are already referring to the variable with the `$` preceding the starting brace `{`, no need for another one in front of the variable name.

Comment: Also, you don't need quotes in the right-hand side of assignments.

Comment: @SatoKatsura That's true.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yeah realized that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `dirname`, `basename` and `awk` commands, you might want to consider this function definition

```
function split {

DIR=$(/bin/dirname "$1")
BASE=$(/bin/basename "$1")
EXT=$(echo "$BASE" | /usr/bin/awk -F. 'NF>1 {print $NF}')
NAME=${BASE%.$EXT}
echo directory=$DIR filename=$NAME extension=$EXT
```

}

```
split good.bye/data.txt
split good.bye/data
split data.txt
split good.bye/data.001.txt
split "good bye/data 001.txt"
```